# libGoogleAnalytics.a missing file

Tags: xcode, google-analytics, swift3

I'll make it short.

I added Firebase to my app via cocoa pods and now I get this warning.
I've tried everything on the net please help.

```
file:///Users/.../Desktop/game/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a: warning: Missing file: /Users/.../Desktop/game/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a is missing from working copy
```

This is my pod file code

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'game' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use     dynamic frameworks


use_frameworks!




#Pods for game


pod 'Firebase/Core'

pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger'


target 'gameTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

target 'gameUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by creating a new project and copying all the files to there.